# Should I use Ecto.Repo in Controller or Model for Elixir Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

For some query in Controller of [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/), there're two plans for me

Plan 1:

```
defmodule Demo.UserController do
  # ...
  def index do
    # This is just for example
    # The point is Repo in used here
    Repo.all(User) 
  end
end
```

Plan 2:

```
defmodule Demo.User do
  # ...
  def all do
    # Put all Repo API and building query logic in Model
    Repo.all(__MODULE__)
  end
end
```

I prefer the Plan 2. Because in most situations, I can put all logic about fetching data in Model.

But I find official guide use Plan 1([docs/model](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/models)) and Phoenix default code `alias Repo` in Controller instead of Model ([web/web.ex](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/installer/templates/new/web/web.ex#L42))

Which one is better? And why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should keep your Repo calls inside your controller. If your logic is complicated then you should consider moving the logic out into its own service module.

You should treat your model functions as pure (free from side effects) so they should only act on data. So for example you could have:

```
def alphabetical(query)
  order_by(query, [u], u.name)
end
```

But you should not have:

```
def alphabetical(query)
  order_by(query, [u], u.name)
  |> Repo.all
end
```

This is because queries are purely data, the call to `Repo.all` has side effects (going off to the database) so it belongs in your controller.

Comment: Hi, I have another question about this problem. If I put Repo calls in controller, how to test the model? Just like your example, should I use Repo to insert some records then do the test(it seems like an integration testing) or just test the result of `order_by`? btw, I have no idea how to test the result of `order_by`.

Comment: In Programming Phoenix we are recommended developers to have two test files in test/models: user_test.exs and user_repo_test.exs. The first one you can test changesets and everything that does not require the repository. The advantage is that you can run with "async: true" on top. The other one requires the repository and it could be the place for you to test complex queries. It all depends on which kind of test you want to write.