# How to make mysql query in controller - elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am very new to Phoenix- Elixir and I want to make mysql query in the controller.

mysql-query: select * from students where first_name = "abc";

Comment: When asking a question if you provide details it helps us to give you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [ecto](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto) and [mariax](https://github.com/xerions/mariaex), you can make a query from anywhere using the functions provided in the [Ecto.Query](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html) module. The [from/2](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2) macro is already imported for you in `web.ex`.

```
def index(conn, params) do
  query = from u in MyApp.User,
    order_by: u.name

  users = Repo.all(query)
end
```

For more complicated queries you may want to move the query (but not the call to `Repo.all` as explained in [Should I use Ecto.Repo in Controller or Model for Elixir Phoenix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340690/should-i-use-ecto-repo-in-controller-or-model-for-elixir-phoenix/34340756#34340756)) into your model.

Comment: iex(14)> query = from s in Chatty.Student,
...(14)> where: s.id > 0,                 
...(14)> select: s                        
#Ecto.Query<from s in Chatty.Student, where: s.id > 0, select: s>
iex(15)> Repo.all(query)                  
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Repo.all/1 (module Repo is not available)
    Repo.all(#Ecto.Query<from s in Chatty.Student, where: s.id > 0, select: s>)

Comment: `Repo` should be `Chatty.Repo` it won't be aliased by default in iex. You can `alias Chatty.Repo` then `Repo` will work.

Comment: Why use "order_by" when the specific MySQL query asked uses "where"

Answer (score 0):

```
MyApp.Repo.all(
    from s in MyApp.Students,
        where: s.first_name == "Mary",
    select s
)
```